# Changing image size relatively to the view in the ListView in Xamarin Forms

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

I have a listView which contains an image, so I would like the image to take its size depending on the view size or container size so that it appears smaller on phones and bigger on tablets. As I know , I can not access and element by its name inside a listView, so what could be the alternitive way to achive that?

Comment: Can't you use `HorizontalOptions` and `VerticalOptions`?

Comment: What do `HorizontalOptions` and `VerticalOptions` have to do with resizing an image?

Comment: So that you can use `FillAndExpand` or `Fill` to fit the size according to the view

Comment: Well I have never thought about it.. It worked actually inside a relative size grid. Thanks man

Comment: :) Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `FillAndExpand` or `Fill` values for `HorizontalOptions` and `VerticalOptions` extentions.